# Revisión por moderadores o empleados para la gente con la cuenta bloqueada para hacer preguntas

Tags: soporte, cuentas-de-usuario

Hace poco me di cuenta de que ya no puedo hacer preguntas en SOes porque estoy bloqueado.

El problema es que textualmente pone que se bloquean al hacer preguntas que no son bien recibidas (spam, fáciles...), que la verdad creo que no es mi caso.

Creo que pasado un tiempo se deberían desbloquear o poder pedir una revisión por un moderador o empleado.

Me gustaría poder deshacerme de este problema.

Tampoco digo que todo el mundo esté pidiendo revisión (aparte tampoco soluciona nada porque se pueden crear otra cuenta perfectamente).

No sé, pero me parece algo molesto e inútil.

Comment: No es facil salir de ese bloqueo. No es por tiempo (puede durar para siempre). Lo mejor que puedes hacer es mejorar las preguntas que ya tienes y esperar tener la suerte de que la comunidad las reciba mejor en un futuro. Asi se sale de ese bloqueo. Te recomiendo leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. Es por ese bloqueo que no me gustan mucho los votos negativos.

Comment: Ademas, parece que te pueden bloquear tambien por tener muchas preguntas sin votos o muchas publicaciones eliminadas. Vi tu usuario, y tienes una pregunta con un voto negativo y varias sin votos. Por lo que parece ser tu caso.

Comment: Si estas proponiendo un cambio a ese sistema de bloqueo, es un cambio para toda la red, por lo tanto el lugar adecuado para proponer el cambio es el meta SE (que esta en ingles)

Comment: ¿Un bloqueo por una pregunta con un voto en contra? Ya me está dando miedo de hacer preguntas. A menos que haya alguna denuncia o reporte en contra por otra cuestión, me parece a todas luces, un bloqueo injustificado.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Hola, me parece que si es tu caso, ya que varias de tus publicaciones han sido reportadas y eliminadas por la comunidad, es muy importante que realices preguntas en base a [ask] y respuestas en base a [answer], cuando puedas volver a escribir en el sitio recuerda realizar publicaciones de acuerdo a lo sugerido por el sitio, saludos.

Comment: te ha votado de forma negativa por que no estoy de acuerdo con este post; o Mejor dicho tu post tiene una orientación a únicamente demeritan el sistema de evaluación de calidad de preguntas y respuesta; finalmente, tu pregunta no aporta una mejora, y tampoco está en el sitio correcto; tu pregunta estaría ubicada mejor en el sitio Principal de META de SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @nadie sin embargo es natural del ser humano el desconocimiento por eso tratare de responder tus dudas.

Comment: @CandidMoe en mi respuesta le sugiero preguntar sobre eso en el chat... hay a lo mejor alguien le pueda dar la mano ... yo pase por ese aro en su momento ... me pelie con medio foro hasta que supe redactar post con mejor calidad... a lo mejor aun no son perfecto y dudo que lo lleguen a ser pero son un poco mas aceptables ...

Answer (score 6):

Si realmente quieres deshacerte del problema te informo que apelando a los moderadores o empleados no es el camino correcto, la limitación de las cuentas ocurren por dos motivos:

1. La plataforma detecta que estás haciendo preguntas malas y te bloquea.
   **Solución:** Debes arreglar tus preguntas editándolas  y mejorarlas; esperar que sean reabiertas y recibir una buena aceptación de la comunidad, todo esto siguiendo las normas del sitio y sugerencia de los usuarios; normalmente cada X cantidad de semana se liberará la posibilidad de hacer una nueva pregunta, si no has hecho nada por solucionar tu problema de calidad de preguntas.
2. Un moderador restringió tu cuenta por hacer spam.
   **Solución:** Debes ir al siguiente sitio https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact y solicitar una revisión de tu caso.

En cualquiera de los dos casos anteriores la responsabilidad de dar seguimiento y solucionar el problema es principalmente del usuario.

***Ahora*** Me he tomado el tiempo de darme una vuelta por tu perfil y veo que solo tienes públicas tus preguntas con buen puntaje... asumo que has borrado algunas preguntas que hiciste que no fueron bien recibidas... eso solo empeora el problema, si no vez tus post borrados están aquí: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/227232)

***La revisión*** como te decía la revisión que existe es hecha en parte por los usuarios que valoran tus aportes y por la plataforma que evalúa si tus preguntas y respuestas son de calidad en la cual toma en cuenta la interacción que tienen tus post con otros usuarios... no es un empleado ni moderador quien hace dicha revisión, aunque como usuarios pueden participar y dependiendo del puntaje de cada usuario la plataforma le dará super poderes como para editar tu post de forma rápida, solicitar cierres, etc; puedes ver la lista de privilegios aquí: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

***¿Es inútil?*** no es inútil como lo argumentas; el 80% de preguntas tiene problemas de calidad o incluso incumplen con las normas del sitio; si esto no se limitara de alguna forma, existirían millones de preguntas molestas que no resolverían los problemas ocupando espacio en las sugerencias. principalmente por que los usuarios no se molestan en evaluar la calidad de sus propias preguntas o respuestas.

Post útiles y relacionados a tu pregunta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Cualquier duda te invito al [chat en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de seguro tus inquietudes pueden ser respondidas y debatidas dentro del marco del respeto.